# Systemd services at boot

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to wrap my brain around how systemd starts services. I'm in the process of writing custom unit files for some services we have.

If I have a service or services that I don't want to start at boot, how do I disable that?

I've read articles that say everything is disabled unless I use systemctl to enable it and then start it. If that's true, and the server reboots, will that service start automatically after it's been enabled once in order to use systemctl to run it? Didn't know if the symlinks created with systemctl enable remain until it's told to be disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable a service so that it does not start on boot :

```
systemctl disable servicename
```

And once you enable a service, It will start automatically when system is rebooted. You don't need to do anything again. 
To enable as service

```
systemctl enable servicename
```

Comment: You can also check whether a service is enabled by entering:


systemctl is-enabled servicename

Comment: This has side-effects of systemd randomly stopping the service in the middle of the night if unattended-upgrade updates it.  Since it's now disabled it won't restart it.